# Unable to bind text to href attribute in VueJS template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, templates, vue-component

I am using VueJS to build a template.

From my 'posts' data, I have been able to bind text into html elements such as **span**, **a**, and **p** using the Mustache syntax. But when I try to bind text into an element attribute such as **href** within the **a** element, it does not work.

I have looked at different tutorials but none show specifically how I can bind text to elements *and* their attributes within the same code - most show one or the other but not together in the same template.

---

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <post v-for="post in posts" :post="post"></post>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="post-template">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a :href="{{posts.url}}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    <p>{{post.text}}</p>
  </li>
</template>
```

My JS looks like this:

```
Vue.component('post', {
  template: "#post-template",
  props: ['post']
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    posts: [
         {
             title: "First post!",
             text: "First text",
             url: "www.firsturl.com"
         },
         {
             title: "Second post!",
             text: "Second text",
             url: "www.secondurl.com"
         },
         {
             title: "Third post!",
             text: "Third text",
             url: "www.thirdurl.com"
         }
    ]}
});
```

---

[See my code in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dstah0945/8wp7e0qy/12/)

Comment: Curly braces are not needed for attributes: `:href="post.url"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In attributes you have to indicate props or JS-expressions directly without mustaches:

```
<a :href="url">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use double bracket on text bind:

```
<a :href="post.url">{{ post.title }}</a>
```