# Why this template works only with :src?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to write a simple gravatar component:

```js
<template>
  <img :src="url" alt="user profile image" />
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
import md5 from "md5";

export default {
  props: {
    email: String,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const hash = computed(() => md5(props.email.trim().toLowerCase()));
    const url = computed(
      () => `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${hash.value}?d=robohash&s=256`
    );

    return {
      url,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

This works but if I replace the  tag with this:

```
<img src="{{ url }}" alt="user profile image" />
```

things no longer work, and the resulting component in the html prints {{ url }} quite literally

```
<img src="{{ url }}" alt="user profile image" class="w-10 h-10 bg-gray-300 rounded-full flex-shrink-0">
```

I'm calling this component with:

```
<Gravatar
  v-bind:email="currentUser.email"
  class="w-10 h-10 bg-gray-300 rounded-full flex-shrink-0"
/>
```

I'm asking because all the documentation I'm looking at favors the `{{ url }}` approach, but it's not working here.

Comment: `:` is short for v-bind, which evaluates the value as js, so `src="{{ url }}"` is just a string, vue doesn't interpolate {{ }} values across the document like in element properties (could you imagine the mess people would do `<{{tag}} {{property}}={{value}} v-model="{{model}}">{{content}}</{{tag}}>`), you need to bind them. use `:src="url"`

Comment: What documentation have you been reading? Vue3 documentation **explicitly mention you should _not_ use mustache syntax in attribute bindings**: "Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes" https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/template-syntax.html#attributes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to bind text to href attribute in VueJS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443346/unable-to-bind-text-to-href-attribute-in-vuejs-template)